# Defining optional attributes in DTD

Tags: xml, dtd

I have something like this:

```
<Tag attr1="" attr2="" attr3="" (0 or more attrX)>
```

I know how to define my DTD regarding the first 3 attributes, just use `#REQUIRED`

However, how do I define the optional 4th to n attributes in the DTD?

Comment: For an optional attribute, you can use `#IMPLIED` in a similar way you use `#REQUIRED`, e.g. `<!ATTLIST Tag  attr4    CDATA  #IMPLIED>`.

Comment: doesn't work for me, because I don't know what the name of these extra attributes will be. Is there no way to specify they presence of more than 3 attributes but only naming the first 3?

Comment: or if that is not possible, then how would I just specify <Tag has some attributes (names and number of which are unknown to the DTD)> ?

Comment: No, with a DTD you can not declare attributes without knowing at first their names. Perhaps with *Schematron* you might something obtain something that would fit your requirements.